# PC won't boot because of TPM enabled

Tags: boot, bios, tpm

I turned TPM on when I was previously booting my PC. Now it can't boot, since there is no TMP connected to the motherboard (there never was one in the first place). There is no video output. After about 30s a continuous high-pitched beep code appears. What are my options?

Comment: Boot into the BIOS and turn it off again?

Comment: There is still no BIOS interface visible on the screen. The beep code seems to be no longer present.

Comment: What evidence besides correlation do you have your problems are connected to enabling TPM when the hardware is missing?

Comment: The booting process was working just fine, until I enabled the TPM in the BIOS.

Comment: @Ramhound I had a similar problem, at work. Trying to install an external graphics card. TPM was only available for the onboard card. After inserting the graphics card, powering up the pc caused an alarm and the pc would not boot. I removed the graphics card, booted the system to windows, shutdown and installed the graphics card. It booted up fine at first with no display. Because of hybrid shutdown, the bios was skipped. Rebooting caused an alarm and the pc would not go on anymore. Disabling TPM solved it.

Comment: @LPChip I sometimes ask questions of users that I already know the answer to in order to get improvements made to a question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you haven't mentioned what haeve you tried, here's some standard procedure for cases when you mess up with the BIOS.

1. Remove any kind of power supply and press the power button for about 30 seconds to completely drain the motherboard (you don't need to remove the cmos clock battery).
2. Look for the motherboard or system specs and search for a jumper to clear or reset config (I haven't seen this on modern systems, though, at most it will just clear the nvram where config is usually stored).
3. If you could activate it without a TPM module present then there must be a way to deactivate it normally, look for the manual on related stuff and follow instructions thoroughly, if any. If not, I think it's a very stupid move from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Removing and re-applying the motherboard battery and therefore resetting the CMOS, seemed to reset the settings and allowed my PC to boot properly

Comment: Damn, beat me by a couple minutes. Glad it works now.